css, makeStyles and useStyles
'&[data-priority="High"]': { background: "red", },
I want to check if the priority is either 1 or High, I am not able to check conditionally
'&[data-priority="High"] &[data-priority="1"]': { background: "red", },

CSS selectors need to be separated by a comma (,) if you want "either", rather than a single selector.

If the comment above doesn't resolve the issue, please add more detail to your question. It's currently extremely minimal and doesn't give a lot of context (or a [mre]) explaining the problem.
